# How to make browser talk to different Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

As browser(external caller) talks to backend service on a single connection, kubernetes respects this connection so that service(`kind: Service`) always divert traffic to same Pod.

[image]

---

If the browser traffic goes to same pod then it becomes difficult to maintain zero downtime, amidst rolling updates.

Below is the spec we are using:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: nginx-loadbalancer
spec:
 type: NodePort
 selector:
    app: my-nginx
 ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    
  - name: "443"
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
```

---

Amidst rolling deployment(`kubectl apply -f file-deployment.yml`), how to maintain zero downtime? amidst such scenario..

Comment: How are you deploying your pods? You shouldn't be creating individual pods, you should be using a `Deployment` resource to create a set of pod replicas that are pointed to by the service.

Comment: @DanielMann yes we are using `Deployment` to create set of pod replicas

Comment: If the client establishes a long-running persistent connection to its server, it should be prepared for occasional disconnects; most HTTP client libraries know how to handle this already.  Do you have a specific setup where deleting a pod causes an operational problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze  This is a ecommerce(retail grocery) backend. So, browser gets connected to backend service until it makes the payment for its shopping. This is the reason for long-running persistent connections. we are using http 1.1

Comment: @overexchange It sounds like your application's architecture is off. Instead of relying on a long-running, persistent HTTP connection, use a queuing mechanism and implement asynchrony. The client submits a payment, the payment request goes into a queue, a payment processor picks up the message and handles it. Then the client can simply receive a notification when payment processing is complete (or incomplete due to a failure) and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @overexchange why do you need the connection to be persistent in the backend? This is probably an achitecture which is not ideal for kubernetes. What you could do as a workaround is setting a high terminationGracePeriod on the pods and have the containers react to SIGTERM and wait with shutting down until all connections are finished. This a not an ideal solution in my view.